# VBA. delete multiple columns, Delete Method of Range Class Failed

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to get this line to work:

```
Sheets("Final Populated Sheet-Business").Range("D:H,J:L,N:R,T:T,X:Z,AC:AK").EntireColumn.Delete
```

I'm getting error `Delete Method of Range Class Failed`

Also tried using `.Delete` vs `.EntreColumn.Delete`

Thanks

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Is there a pivot table on the sheet? Is the sheet protected?

Comment: Sheets are unprotected.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem either

Comment: Is there a pivot table on the sheet? What happens when you try to delete these columns *manually*?